# No module named 'bbox'

Tags: python, pycharm, cython, face-detection, faster-rcnn

I am working on one project which should be re written, so i did not write from beginning, and there is no opportunity to ask person who wrote the code.

I have next part of code:

```
from ..cython.bbox import bbox_overlaps_cython

def bbox_overlaps(boxes, query_boxes):
    return bbox_overlaps_cython(boxes, query_boxes)
```

Then this error comes out:

```
from ..cython.bbox import bbox_overlaps_cython
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lib.rcnn.cython.bbox'
```

I already tried to build like `python3 setup.py build_ext --inplace` in the same directory where setup.py is located, but error is the same.

The tree of folders is next:

rcnn

--cython

----bbox.pyx

----setup.py

--processing

----bbox_transform.py

Comment: i found solution in https://github.com/deepinsight/insightface/issues/1265#issuecomment-731703155
but it does not make any sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to propose a solution without knowing more about your environment and how you're invoking the code that throws the error.

Like any module, that `bbox` module needs to be installed into your environment and also visible to the Python runtime when you invoke your code. At least one of these things is not as it should be.

- Is the `bbox` module installed into your environment? What is in that `setup.py`?
- How are you invoking the code? From which directory?

The import `from ..cython.bbox import bbox_overlaps_cython` uses a [relative path](https://realpython.com/absolute-vs-relative-python-imports/#relative-imports) to find the `bbox` module, so it makes an assumption about the location of the module relative to the file where the import happens.

You might find that invoking the code from the directory above or below solves the problem. Or, assuming that the module is present and correct in one of those directories, you might be able to add the location of the `bbox` module to the [PYTHONPATH](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pythonpath-environment-variable-in-python/) so that the import statement knows where to find it at runtime.